# How do you normalize a histogram from the hist() function of MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, normalize

I wish to normalize my histogram, but for some reason I get some error in my code.

```
N = 1000;
mu = 5; stdev = 2;
x = mu+stdev*randn(N,1);
bin=mu-6*stdev:0.5:mu+6*stdev;
f=hist(x,bin);
plot(bin,f,'bo');

counts = f.Values;
sum_counts = sum(counts);
width = f.BinWidth;

area = sum_counts*width;
```

I get to plot my histogram but I get an error in normalization. I know that the histogram() function supports normalization but I am trying to avoid that.

```
Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type.
     counts = f.Values;
```

Comment: Does this help?
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/89639-normalized-distribution-for-histogram

Comment: I'm not sure if it did, but my plot looks different now. It  initially looked like a bell curve. Now it is inverted.

Answer (score 0):

when you write `f=hist(x,bin);` you assign the values of the histogram to `f` as a vector, as you saw. normalization such that the area under the curve is 1, is then just `f./sum(f)` ...

Answer (score 0):

Note that `hist` is no longer recommended and has been replaced by `histogram`.

There are normalisation options as name-value pairs when creating the histogram.
`histogram(x,bin,'Normalization','pdf');` or `histogram(x,bin,'Normalization','probability');`, for example, may be what you are looking for. The full range of normalisation options can be found in the [doc](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html#d123e624316).